How to extract YYYYMMDD from gitlab predefined variable in variables: section (not later in script section)
I have a .gitlab-ci.yml with lots of variables which are defined sequentially from some earlier variables.
Instead of beginning with a hardcoded timestamp I want to use the predefined CI_JOB_STARTED_AT but I only want the YYYYMMDD part of it.
I tried this
variables:
  # full ISO8601 timestamp, keep yyyy-mm-dd
  TEMP_REV1: "${CI_JOB_STARTED_AT:0:10}"
  # remove all "-"
  TEMP_REV2: "${TEMP_REV1//-/}"
  TARGET_IMAGE_REV:
    value: "${TEMP_REV2}01"
    description: "yyyymmdd## timestamp+version# for image"
  TARGET_RELEASE_TAG: "${TARGET_IMAGE_VERSION}-${TARGET_IMAGE_REV}"
  # ... etc.

But it doesn't work, the variable appears empty. I'd have to define ~10 other variables if I moved all of it into the script section.
Is this possible?

Is this the "variable" section of a Job or of your pipeline? CI_JOB_STARTED_AT is only defined for jobs

I see that the variables are empty when a job runs. I try to define the variable as global, as I have blocks in the .yml file for multiple platforms (x86 and s390).

Ok this is really weird... I just tested it and you are right, CI_JOB_STARTED_AT is always empty for me if I try to use it in a variable section, does not matter if it is at job level or globally. But it does work in the script section. Would it be possible for you to maybe use a job template with a before_script section to set your TARGET_RELEASE_TAG?
